# VBA code to go back to previous value of particular cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a doubt with my current VBA code and I have no idea how to rectify that. Any help pls.

I am trying to give user a popup msg, if cell value is less than max value of certain range and then go back to previous value of same cell. for this I wrote a code to bring back the last entered value to this cell. But the problem here is last value entered in the some other cell got pasted here after the macro fired.

also I have same code for other cell, if cell value is more than 100, it will give a message and goes to back to previous value. this works fine but when the above code runs previous value of this one goes to above code.

This may not be very clear. Please find the code below. I am ready to answer.

```
Dim oval
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address(0, 0) = "G1" Then
    If Range("L2") < 100 Then
      MsgBox "No further pressure drop at higher operating temperatures !",  vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Calculation can't run"
      Range("G1") = G1Value
    Else: End If
  Else: End If
  If Range("G2") < WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("I11:I21")) Then
    MsgBox "Input pressure is low"
    Range("G2") = oval
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = Range("G1") Then
    G1Value = Range("G1")
  Else: End If
  oval = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Application.Undo` to cancel edits that don't verify your rules.

Comment: I suggest you rethink your solution and start from scratch

Comment: put your "form" that users fill with data on "inputSheet". keep your data on "dataSheet". when a value is entered into the inputSheet, it is validated, and either passed to dataSheet, or rejected. the users are not allowed to update dataSheet directly

Comment: I tried for Application.undo method. Problem is in certain time when my sheet runs a calculation, further undo is not working. I mean there will be more time undo is required.

Comment: @jsotola Is there any code for your suggestion? or u mean to create userform for that?